# Oh go dear! again... we Here

Tags: cipher, visual, missing-digits

What is the missing one?

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, $[image: Statistically I would go for 1.]

*[Some colours look alike, sorry about that, but then again you don't really need to be able to make a visual difference between them, do you? Oh and sorry for being slightly inconsistent just there - not a native speaker.]*

---

**Hint:**

> Should same colour digits be read from top to bottom or from left to right?

---

[Here is a google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xdJOTS62hnBN6_4LGKFfaN64YkSdUqqaggHrwMuBrOU/edit?usp=sharing) required by OmegaKrypton to make any analysis easier.

Comment: the answer is given in the puzzle. “what is the missing ONE”

Comment: @OmegaKrypton This doesn't explain a lot.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Rot13(Fgngvfgvpnyyl V jbhyq tb sbe 1)

Comment: @Ak19 That's one of the hints :) keep it up!

Comment: Hey, every row and column has all 6 colors. Is that a hint?

Comment: @Alto It is not by accident. I think that on PSE people usually rot13 this kind of questions though.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Also, rot13(Vf gur gvgyr n uvag? Naq jul ner gur 1'f va fhfcvpvbhf qvntbanyf? Uzzzz....) [I hope I'm not making it more complicated than it is]

Comment: @Alto rot13(Bs pbhefr vg vf. Nf sbe gur qvntbanyf V'yy yrg lbh svaq bhg jurgure vg'f zrnavatshy).

Comment: could you give us the hex/rgb value of the bg colour of each of the cells? or a google sheets? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I included a Google sheet in the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Answer:

> It's E!

Reasoning:

> Using the RGB hex values for the colors given results in:

.

> [image: hex values],

.

> where the rows are, top to bottom, in the order of the first row by color.  The colors in the rows in the original image are always in the same order from left to right, just shifted for each row.  Reading the values by color from left to right, and arranging the rows in the same way, we get:

.

> [image]

.

> which happens to be the same.  In summary, the numbers/letters associated with each color are, from left to right, the same as the RGB hex values for the associated color.

EDIT: Formatting

Comment: You got the right answer! Can you also explain the different hints (such as the title and how the numbers in the grid were chosen)?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier - I'm not sure... Is the title rot13(Onfrq ba gur iregvpny cbfvgvba bs gur erq nf lbh tb sebz yrsg gb evtug)? I am also stumped as to how Ak19's find fits in... Perhaps someone else has an idea?

Comment: Yes, but not only that. What @Ak19 found is a hint to find the meaning of the numbers.